# Printing contents of any vector

Tags: c++, templates

I have a debug class that I use in my code to print various things. In this class I overload `operator()` to facilitate output. I have several `operator()`s to print vectors. When I added a template version, I came accross compile errors.

Here is the code:

```
  template<class Type1>
    inline debug&
    operator()(const std::string& name,
               typename std::vector<Type1>::const_iterator begin,
               typename std::vector<Type1>::const_iterator end)
    {    
      _stream << indent(internal) << "< " << name << " : [ ";
      std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<Type1>(_stream, " "));
      _stream << "] >" << std::endl;

      return *this;
    }
```

And another vector print function I have:

```
  inline debug&
  operator()(const std::string& name,
             typename std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator begin,
             typename std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator end)
  {
    _stream << indent(internal) << "< " << name << " : [ " << std::hex;
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<uint32_t>(_stream, " "));
    _stream << "] >" << std::endl;

    return *this;
  }
```

Where `indent()` does exactly what it says.

Here is the compile error:

```
../include/debug.hh:146:3: note: template<class Type1> relix::debug&    relix::debug::operator()(const string&, typename std::vector<_RealType>::const_iterator, typename std::vector<_RealType>::const_iterator)
../include/debug.hh:146:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
assembler.cc:78:64: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Type1’
```

Here is assembler.cc:78:

```
  log(D_C(tl._tokens), tl._tokens.begin(), tl._tokens.end());
```

Where `D_C()` is a substitution preprocessor macro to extract the variable name and `_tokens` is a `std::vector` of `token`, where `token` has an overloaded `operator<<()`.

Comment: Please create the smallest possible program that demonstrates the problem, and copy-paste that entire program in your question. http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with just the template:

```
template<class Type1>
inline debug&
operator()(const std::string& name,
           typename std::vector<Type1>::const_iterator begin,
           typename std::vector<Type1>::const_iterator end)
{    
// ...
```

The problem here is that `Type1` cannot be deduced by the compiler. Consider what would be needed to actually deduce the type: The compiler would have to instantiate `std::vector` with *all* possible types, including any potential instantiation of `std::vector` to determine whether the argument to the function is a match.

The simplest workaround is to drop `vector` from the explicit requirements in the signature and convert it to:

```
template<class Iterator>
inline debug&
operator()(const std::string& name,
           Iterator begin,
           Iterator end)
{    
// ...
```

Now the type can be trivially deduced, whatever the argument to the function is.

Comment: Then is there a way to specialize the template for iterators of certain types (i.e. for std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator) or will the compiler match it to the second function automatically?

Comment: @nerozehl: You can specialize, in exactly the way that you stated (but without the `typename`), but for functions it is usually better to *override*: `inline debug& operator()( const std::string& name, std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator begin, ...` Note that in the *specialization* there is no type to *deduce*, you are telling it what the exact type is.

Comment: I tried your method but I get a slew of errors from /home/nerozehl/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/iterator:66:0, about no known conversions to the types that I use that can be output.

Comment: The problem seems to be with `std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<IteratorT>(_stream, " "));`

Comment: If I change it to `for(auto i = begin; i != end; i++) _stream << (*i) << " ";` it works, too.

Comment: With ostream_iterator<T>, T is the value type, not the iterator type.

Comment: Even more so, because iterators may not carry any container information (might be bare pointers), not only would the compiler have to test against all possible vector instantiations, but against almost everything.

Comment: The only problem I'm having now is that the compiler is always using the template, not the overloaded functions.

Comment: @nerozehl: You might want to post a question with the actual (updated) code. The overload should be picked up over the template whenever the arguments are of the appropriate type (i.e. with no conversions)

Comment: Ok I did that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469219/overloaded-function-not-being-used)