# Overloaded Function not being Used:

Tags: c++, templates

I have two functions that I have overloaded for my debug class:

```
  template<class IteratorT>
    inline debug&
    operator()(const std::string& name,
               IteratorT begin,
               IteratorT end)
    {
      _stream << indent(internal) << "g< " << name << " : [ ";
      for (auto i = begin; i != end; i++)
        _stream << (*i) << " ";
      _stream << "] >" << std::endl;

      return *this;
    }
```

And

```
  inline debug&
  operator()(const std::string& name,
             std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator begin,
             std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator end)
  {
    _stream << indent(internal) << "u8< " << name << " : [ " << std::hex;
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<uint32_t>(_stream, " "));
    _stream << "] >" << std::endl;

    return *this;
  }
```

Here is a snipped of how it's used:

```
int main()
{
  debug log;

  std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
  vec.push_back(0xde);
  vec.push_back(0xad);
  vec.push_back(0xc0);
  vec.push_back(0xde);

  log("vec", vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

The output is (since it's not being printed as hex characters I ommited the unformatted result):

```
g< "vec" : [ ... ] >
```

Instead of

```
u8< "vec" : [ de ad c0 de ] >
```

For some reason the compiler isn't picking the correct, overloaded function.

```
$ g++47 --version
g++47 (GCC) 4.7.0 20120224 (experimental)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the code is that overload resolution only considers the arguments to the function and not how the result is going to be used. That means that the expression `vec.begin()` (conversely `vec.end()`) only considers that `vec` is a non-const vector, and it is thus using the non-const version.

While there is an implicit conversion from `std::vector<>::iterator` to `std::vector<>::const_iterator`, this required conversion deems the overload as a worse candidate for resolution than the template function with the type substitution being `std::vector<>::iterator`.

As of workarounds, you can overload for both `iterator` and `const_iterator` (best solution, as the solution is in just the callee) or you can fix the calls by forcing the vector to be const by means of a cast: `static_cast<const std::vector<uint8_T>& >(vec).begin()` (which is ugly and requires the fix to be applied in all calls, which is hard to maintain)

Comment: Okay. On a side note, is the overload better than a partial specialization?

Comment: a partial specialization would be used if you wanted special behaviour for all vector iterators over general ones. Not sure if it's possible to partially-specialize on iterators whose value_type is uint8_t

Comment: @nerozehl: You cannot partially specialize a function, so the question has a clear simple answer... possible vs. impossible. Now, you could move the function to be a static non-template member function of a template class, in which case you could partially specialize, gaining flexibility at the cost of extra code. But I am not sure that you would get much out of it. On the other hand, if you mean a *full* specialization of the function, overloads should be preferred, but I cannot recall the exact details of why/where it mattered... google for it :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your specialization isn't being called because you are passing `vector<uint8_t>::iterator` not `vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator` and it finds an exact match through the template.

To fix, you either create an overload also for non-const iterators or create a const-reference to your vector and call `begin()` / `end()` on that.

Comment: Doesn't `std::vector` have `const_iterator begin () const;` which should be matched?

Comment: @nerozehl: Read my answer, overload resolution only considers the arguments and not how the result is going to be used. In this case, because the vector is not constant, it will pick up `iterator begin();` as the best candidate for the `vec.begin()` call.

Answer (score 1):

It is selecting the generic version because you are passing a `vector<uint8_t>::iterator` rather than a `vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator`. You should add a third `operator()` that takes the non-`const` version and passes it to the `const` one.